# Can RTSP be used for playbacks?

Tags: rtsp, playback

I cannot find a clear answer to this question. From what I understand, RTSP is a protocol for live streams only. Is this correct? Does RTSP support commands to play footage that has been already recorded, say, days or weeks ago?

Comment: What part of the question remains unanswered to you after your research?

Comment: @Jay Does RTSP support commands to play footage that has been already recorded, say, days or weeks ago? The answer seems like no, but it's a bit unclear.

Comment: Of course it does I am not sure why you would think otherwise...

Comment: @Jay Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

RTSP does support playbacks.

Here is an example of Hikvision format for a real time and a playback url.

**Real time:** rtsp://{device.Username}:{device.Password}@{device.Host}/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/{channel}

**playback:** rtsp://{device.Username}:{device.Password}@{device.Host}/Streaming/tracks/{trackId}/?starttime={startTime_str}&endtime={endTime_str}